# Populating Dictionary based on user selection in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following things are retrieved from CSV files.

```
language = {"english" : {"item1":"File","item2":"Accounts"},
            "tamil"   : {"item1":"கோப்பு","item2":"கணக்கியல்"},
            "Hindi"   : {"item1":"Hindi_File","item2":"Hindi_accounts"}}

scut = {"user1":[{"id":"file","scut":"Alt+F"},{'id':"accounts","scut":"F5"}],
        "user2":[{"id":"file","scut":"Ctrl+F"},{'id':"accounts","scut":"F8"}]}

menu = {"lbl01"    :{"id":"file","item1":"","item2":"","scut":""},
         "lbl02":{"id":"accounts","item1":"","item2":"","scut":""}}

selection = ["english","tamil"]
user = ["user1"]
```

Based On this data , I need to populate the dictionary as follows:

```
result = {"lbl01" :{"id":"file","item1":"File","item2":"கோப்பு","scut":"Alt+F"},
           "lbl02":{"id":"accounts","item1":"Accounts","item2":"கணக்கியல்","scut":"F5"}}
```

For Example, In My case, My first Language option is "English"  and my second language option is "Tamil" and log in with "User1", so My result dicionery "item1","item2",scut" is replaced with "File","Accounts","Alt+F".

Comment: So what is the problem

Comment: @ Andang Sudrajat, Can't able to achieve it

Comment: Can you include the codes you have been working so we can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
language = {"english" : {"item1":"File","item2":"Accounts"},
            "tamil"   : {"item1":"கோப்பு","item2":"கணக்கியல்"},
            "Hindi"   : {"item1":"Hindi_File","item2":"Hindi_accounts"}}

scut = {"user1":[{"id":"file","scut":"Alt+F"},{'id':"accounts","scut":"F5"}],
        "user2":[{"id":"file","scut":"Ctrl+F"},{'id':"accounts","scut":"F8"}]}

menu = {"file"    :{"id":"file","item1":"","item2":"","scut":""},
         "accounts":{"id":"accounts","item1":"","item2":"","scut":""}}

selection = ["english","tamil"]
user = ["user1"]


result = {}
for index, item in enumerate(menu.keys()):
    result[item] = {} 
    result[item].update(menu[item])
    result[item].update(language[selection[index]])
    result[item].update(scut[user[0]][index])
```

This is my answer